# compare two data frames and extract rows of interest

Tags: python, pandas

I changed this post due to lack of response and asking to broad of a question on my part, I think.I have taken the original csv and grouped/ selected out all the records that are the latest and placed them in a new df as well as created another df without the latest records.

I have two data frames, one with a the latest version of that record:

```
new_df = [{'ful_id':000c1a6c-1f1c, 'version':3, 'xs':123, 'at_grade':yes, 'date':20171003},
          {'ful_id':00dc5fec-ddb8, 'version':2, 'xs':556, 'at_grade':   , 'date':20171009}]
```

and another with older versions of that record:

```
old = [{'ful_id':000c1a6c-1f1c, 'version':2, 'xs':   , 'at_grade':yes, 'date':20170902},
       {'ful_id':000c1a6c-1f1c, 'version':1, 'xs':   , 'at_grade':yes, 'date':20170810},
       {'ful_id':00dc5fec-ddb8, 'version':1, 'xs':556, 'at_grade':no, 'date':20170803}]
```

*Data example though the real spread sheet has 130 columns and 20k plus records

I need to run through each record compare ids and then loop through all versions of that id and see if data was deleted in the new version that was in the old. I do not care about other changes, ex if the new version contains data that the old did not. So I was thinking about doing a Boolean comparison? The output would be a any record id missing info along with the column that was changed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    #empty table for comparison
compare = []
#now im not sure how to proceed
for i,r in new_df.iterrows():
    if (current['ful_id']== old_v['ful_id']):
        turn values into boolean and compare any([])
           if value is false in new version but true in old 
               compare.append
    else :
        continue through next id group
```

The last part is not *code* I know, im just unsure how to proceed
For my output I would like a csv with the id and columns that that are different then the current version. So for the example above, only one record and one column would be in the output due to the current version having no at_grade value.

```
ful_id         at_grade
00dc5fec-ddb8    false
```

Comment: Please provide a sample data set and expect output. That'll help us solve it. Mere code doesn't help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you give the expected output of your toy example?